# Bus Driver's Age?

Tags: logical-deduction, lateral-thinking

Imagine:
You are a bus driver that drives from Delhi to Karachi and exactly 1987 kilometers. 1 liter fuel can end upto 105 kilometers . Every time driver stops at a fuel station he fills 3 liters of fuel and leaves 15 passengers at the fuel station and after driving 210 kilometers take up 17 new passengers.
On the basis that driver only stops at a fuel station when his fuel tank is approximately empty.(Take at a fuel station fuel in bus 0 liters.)

Determine the age of the BUS DRIVER ?

Comment: This question has too many answers.

Answer (score 4):

The age of the bus driver is

> 23, because I'm driving the bus.